# How to retrieve all nodes of tree-like structure of document in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, tree

I've got model tree structure with parent references. Other words, any node can store the id of the node’s parent likes the following:

```
{ 
   _id: "1"
},
{ 
   _id: "2",
   _parent: "1"
},
{ 
   _id: "3",
   _parent: "1"
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is retrieving all nodes (including parent node itself) by providing node id. For the structure above I'd like to get something like the following:

```
getJSON({_id: "1"}, function (flat) {
    // flat
    // [{_id: 1}, {_id: 2}, {_id: 3}]
});
```

Could suggest a proper way of doing this in NodeJS and mongoose provider?

Comment: Documentation - [Model Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/). There are six different cases there with different approaches and solutions. Choose one.

Comment: @NeilLunn I saw these examples and have chosen the first one. This doc only describes possible data modeling but leaves processing out of the tutorial. The only mentioning about this is `The Parent Links pattern provides a simple solution to tree storage but requires multiple queries to retrieve subtrees.`

Comment: `db.categories.find( { parent: "Databases" } )` That's the processing. If you think you want something different, "choose another one".

Comment: I don't think that your code would work because of 2 reasons: 1) It doesn't affect parent node itself; 2) What if some child node (e.g _id: 2) has child nodes also?

Comment: Dude. It's not the solution to your problem, it's the solution to how the "example" is actually meant to work. If you are trying to make that example do something else "then you picked the wrong modelling technique". Go and read the other ones and learn which suits your needs and implement that technique.  As the saying goes, "trying to fit a square peg into a round hole". It's meant to demonstrate futility.

Comment: I've already chosen this approach and now trying to find answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested, I've found [this](https://www.codementor.io/slavko/storing-tree-structures-in-mongodb-example-code-du107tk8d#getting-all-node-descendants) approach that solves my task.

```
var descendants=[]
var stack=[];
var item = db.categoriesPCO.findOne({_id:"Cell_Phones_and_Accessories"});
stack.push(item);
while (stack.length>0){
    var currentnode = stack.pop();
    var children = db.categoriesPCO.find({parent:currentnode._id});
    while(true === children.hasNext()) {
        var child = children.next();
        descendants.push(child._id);
        stack.push(child);
    }
}


descendants.join(",")
//Cell_Phones_and_Smartphones,Headsets,Batteries,Cables_And_Adapters,Nokia,Samsung,Apple,HTC,Vyacheslav
```

Comment: You are aware of the fact that with materialized paths or array of ancestors, this would be a simple and efficient query instead of a potentially very costly recursive operation?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg yes I'am. But `materialized paths` approach has drawbacks in terms of atomicity.

Comment: Which ones would that be?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg when I create a child node I need to perform 2 commands: 1 - create child node, 2 - update `path` field of  parent node.

Comment: Nope. The path of the parent remains untouched. Will post an according answer tomorrow.